# nuxtjs vuetify v-img placeholder not working

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

under nuxt.js i'm using vuetify. v-img works, but as i try to use the 'placeholder' feature, as described in the docs, it does not work. for the example i copy exactly the example that works in the docs.
we suppose to see a circle loader while we wait for the image.
for testing, i'm using chrome to slow down the connection.
this doesn't work. there is a blank for a few seconds, then the image appears. 
here is the code. any idea?

```
<v-col cols="4">
  <v-img :src="selectedItem.picture">
    <template v-slot:placeholder>
       <v-row class="fill-height ma-0" align="center" justify="center">
         <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="blue"></v-progress-circular>
       </v-row>
    </template>
  </v-img>
</v-col>
```

note: i'm not using vuetify-loader. could this be the issue?

Comment: It doesn't see any error here. What does your console say?

Comment: Nothing. I was hoping to see the spinner going until the picture loads, but it doesn't. just empty space, and then the picture shows up.  I am using dev tools to cause the access to server to be slower (network, 3G slow).  No errors in console.

Comment: Your code is working after adding an aspect ratio props to the v-img.

Comment: Yes! thank you, this solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Better use 'default' slot and show it while checking `@error="imgLoadStatus='error'"` of image.
For me, sometimes in runtime while dynamically loading and changing image, placeholder was not showing up at all.